# How to relate object with organization?

Tags: account, object

Hello I am absolutely beginner with salesforce. I have  got a test  task on my job interview. I have done everything except one small task . Because I don't know how to implement it in salesforce ( i cant find functionality).

My question is following:

1. I have created transport object with two field name of transport an status .
   Than the author ask me to relate my object with organisation(Account) through the field lookup field.  I cant find this lookup field. And I thought that I have to relate my transport object with account using  corresponding fields . But in my object there are no fields for this relation. Or I don't understand something .

Comment: So. you are able to post the problem during interview! Anyways, you need to create lookup type field on Transport object.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this you would need to create an additional field on the Transport SObject of type lookup. After you create a new record of your Transport Object you can then link it to the Organization(Account) through the new created field.

Additionally if the record you want to link it to it's always the same you could create a workflow which populates your lookup field to the specific record id.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create a new field whose data type will be "Lookup Relationship" and selected related to as "account".simple and easy.